# How to login user after sending confirmation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, overriding, devise-confirmable

I use devise to authenticate users on my website with the devise confirmable option. Now, when users sign up they do get a confirmation email, but I need user automatically logged in after sending confirmation.

I want users to be able to sign in even without confirming their email address.

I understand I need to modify the confirmation controller, but don't know what and how. Here's my code:

```
class Devise::ConfirmationsController < DeviseController
# GET /resource/confirmation/new
def new
 build_resource({})
end

# POST /resource/confirmation
def create
 self.resource = resource_class.send_confirmation_instructions(resource_params)
if successfully_sent?(resource)
  respond_with({}, :location => 
after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
else
  respond_with(resource)
 end
end

 # GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef
def show
 self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])

if resource.errors.empty?
  set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
   respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
 else
  respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity){ render :new }
 end
end

protected

# The path used after resending confirmation instructions.
def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
  new_session_path(resource_name)
end

# The path used after confirmation.
def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
  after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end

 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the devise initializer, around line 87, you should see this:

```
# ==> Configuration for :confirmable
# A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
# confirming his account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
# able to access the website for two days without confirming his account,
# access will be blocked just in the third day. Default is 0.days, meaning
# the user cannot access the website without confirming his account.
# config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days
```

Enabling this allows your users to sign in for a period of time without confirming their account through the confirmations email. If you want to automatically sign the user in after sending the confirmation email, then you will need to override the `create` method in the the Devise [confirmations_controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb). There are tutorials out there on how to override Devise controllers, but you will want to do something like:

```
def create
  self.resource = resource_class.send_confirmation_instructions(resource_params)

  if successfully_sent?(resource)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with({}, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    respond_with(resource)
  end
end
```

Which is basically the default Devise method, with the extra line to sign in the user and changing the `respond_With` with call to be `after_sign_up_path_for`. Take note that the `after_sign_up_path_for` defaults to the root route which may be undesirable. There are examples on the Devise Wiki about overriding this path.